# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.rubensousa:bottomsheetbuilder:1.6.1

Tags: android, manifest

I'm trying to install the following dependency: https://github.com/rubensousa/BottomSheetBuilder

But it gives me the following errors:

[image]

I am not able to understand what the errors that are given to me may be due to.

This is the build.gradle file I'm using.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.exoplayer"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.rubensousa:previewseekbar:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.rubensousa:previewseekbar-exoplayer:2.8.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.8.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
    implementation 'com.github.rubensousa:bottomsheetbuilder:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
}
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: did you connect to internet?

Comment: @Radesh: Yes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

logs are showing error on test packages. check your test packages to see if their classes are not removed. 
and just for your own check, comment test dependencies and build again to see if error remains or not

Comment: Where do I find these pachege tests? What should I do to comment on them?

Comment: you can find them in java folder, beside your main package.
to comment test dependencies go to your app level gradle file and in dependency segment find "testImplementation" and "androidTestImplementation" and press "Ctrl" + "/" to comment them.

Comment: I solved by commenting
     testImplementation 'junit: junit: 4.12'
     androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test: runner: 1.0.2'
     androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso: espresso-core: 3.0.2'
Then I re-commented, and it works.
but I do not know why. ;)

Comment: these type of errors sometimes happen out of nothing in android studio!